# Hall effect sensor and water sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors

I'm working on a project based on the two sensor above but I keep getting this error:

'liquid_level does not name a type'

This is my sketch:

```
/*
YF‐ S201 Water Flow Sensor
Water Flow Sensor output processed to read in litres/hour
Adaptation Courtesy: www.hobbytronics.co.uk
*/
const int sensorPin= 0; //sensor pin connected to analog pin A0
int liquid_level;
volatile int flow_frequency; // Measures flow sensor pulses
unsigned int l_hour; // Calculated litres/hour
unsigned char flowsensor = 2; // Sensor Input
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long cloopTime;
void flow () // Interrupt function
{
   flow_frequency++;
}
void setup()
{

   pinMode(flowsensor, INPUT);
   pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(flowsensor, HIGH); // Optional Internal Pull-Up
   Serial.begin(9600);
   attachInterrupt(0, flow, RISING); // Setup Interrupt
   sei(); // Enable interrupts
   currentTime = millis();
   cloopTime = currentTime;
}
void loop ()
{ 
   currentTime = millis();
   // Every second, calculate and print litres/hour
   if(currentTime >= (cloopTime + 1000))
   {
      cloopTime = currentTime; // Updates cloopTime
      // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in L/min.
      l_hour = (flow_frequency * 60 / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flowrate in L/hour
      flow_frequency = 0; // Reset Counter
      Serial.print(l_hour, DEC); // Print litres/hour
      Serial.println(" L/hour");

   }
}

liquid_level= analogRead(sensorPin); //arduino reads the value from the liquid level sensor
Serial.println(liquid_level);//prints out liquid level sensor reading
delay(100);//delays 100ms
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to re-write your post in order to have more readable code. :)

Answer (score 2):

The last 4 lines are outside any function. They aren’t in the `loop()` function. You can’t put plain statements outside of any function. Check your brackets.